# MVC4 Razor tags in swapped out JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a View using swapped out JavaScript

```
@section JavaScript {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/Index.js")" />
}
```

I know I can call Razor commands in a JavaScript section directly within my View, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var someVariable = '@(Model.Name)'
</script>
```

Now, I need to call a custom HtmlHelperExtension Method returning a string value from my swapped out .js file, but when I write it down like this:

```
var someVariable = '@(Html.someHtmlFunction())'
```

the part '@(Html.someHtmlFunction())' gets interpreted as string itself and my someVariable looks like "@(Html.someHtmlFunction())" instead of "someReturnValue".

Is it possible to call a Razor command from within a swapped out JavaScript file or do I have to include the JavaScript in the View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do this in the .js file. What I normally do in these scenarios is set the JavaScript variable on the page and reference it in the .js file. I.e. use `global` variable:

in .cshtml:

```
var someVariable = '@(Html.someHtmlFunction())' // make sure this is before .js
@section JavaScript {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/Index.js")" />
}
```

in Index.js:

```
console.log(someVariable);
```